# Safari: Is it possible to override the native 'elements' member of <form> elements?

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, safari

In our web application framework, we extend the DOM by adding an 'elements' member to all DOM objects that is a shortcut to the somewhat awkwardly named 'querySelectorAll':

```
Element.prototype.elements = Element.prototype.querySelectorAll;
```

This causes problems in iOS Safari because appearently, the native 'elements' member of <form> elements is somehow "protected" and still returns a list of form children, instead of being replaced by querySelectorAll.

Is there any way to force this to work?

Comment: Have you tried for other method names, eg `.qSA` instead of `elements`, or does that result in the same problem?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, other names work, and 'elements' works on all other element types. It seems like if an element type already has a native member '.elements' (like FORM does), it cannot be replaced in Safari.